# Create multiple strings inside a string using python

Tags: python, string

I am new to using python to write `sql` strings and was wondering if someone could help me. So currently I am writing a `sql` statement like this,

```
   sql_statement = """SELECT * from some_database WHERE FirstName IN (%(first_names)s)"""
   first_names = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3']
```

And I want the string to end up like this `SELECT * from some_database WHERE FirstName IN ('fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3')`, where each element in the list becomes its own string in the `sql`statement. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: If you are calling `cur.execute`, try: `cur.execute("""SELECT * from some_database WHERE FirstName IN (?)""", first_names)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.format) to accomplish this:

```
>>> sql_statement = """SELECT * from some_database WHERE FirstName IN {}"""
>>> first_names = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3']
>>> 
>>> sql_statement.format(repr(tuple(first_names)))
"SELECT * from some_database WHERE FirstName IN ('fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3')"
>>>
```

**Caveat:** While this is fine as just a plain string, be very careful using this as a SQL statement due to SQL injection. A better idea would most likely  be to [`cursor.execute`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) instead or the equivalent in your SQL API library.

Comment: This is fine on its own but remember SQL injection is always a problem when dealing with SQL statements.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, that is a valid point and I'm aware of that fact. I was simply providing what the OP asked for.

Comment: @ChristianDean: May I suggest adding a caveat to your reply given the nature of the question (not just "any" string substitution, it's a SQL query)?

A lot of people do Stack Overflow Driven Development (implement first answer on SO that "works"). Your answer will probably be accepted because it will work and then others will search for something similar, see your reply, and then go with it not bothering to read the comments and, worst, the *docs*.

It may be tempting to consider their fate as natural selection. I would've been dead were it not for charitable souls.

Comment: @JugurthaHadjar Alright, you've convinced me. I'll add one.

Comment: Thanks.. Sorry to bother you again: the caveat isn't in using `cursor.execute` to avoid SQL injection (we need to execute the query to have an injection in the first place), it's about handling parameters *properly*.

For further information, see [PEP249 (Python Database Specification v2.0)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

One attribute to pay attention to is `paramstyle`. Whether you use `sqlite3` or `psycopg2`, etc:  sqlite3.paramstyle returns `'qmark'` and `psycopg2.paramstyle` returns `'pyformat'`.

Comment: @JugurthaHadjar Okay, thanks for that information. To be honest, I have zero experience with using SQL, so I wasn't exactly sure what to add.  Feel free to edit my answer with a proper caveat and I'll accept it.